# JavaScript/AngularJS : How do i declare directive from from javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to declare my html tag(angular directive) as below in javascript. How do i do with correct js syntax.

```
$scope.myList =[ {title='Angular1' content='<div angular-one></div>'},

                 {title='Angular2' content='<div angular-two></div>'}];
```

I will bind this value back to html later. I just want to know how do declare above angular-one and angular-two directives inside the div tag using javascript.

in the html, i will call the passed value from javascript and bind the directive in the html.

```
{{content}}
```

my directive get displayed as string like  instead of binding as html.

Comment: can you explain what are you exactly trying to achieve? do you want to create a direct?

Comment: @S4beR  i have updated my question.

Comment: I am still not sure what are you trying to do. can you **share some example** on **jsfiddle** or **plnkr** or any other place

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple, all what you need it's to create a simple directive to compile the html (using the $compile service from angular):

```
.directive('compile', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(
            function(scope) {
                // watch the 'compile' expression for changes
                return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
            },
            function(value) {
                // when the 'compile' expression changes
                // assign it into the current DOM
                element.html(value);

                // compile the new DOM and link it to the current
                // scope.
                // NOTE: we only compile .childNodes so that
                // we don't get into infinite loop compiling ourselves
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            }
        );
    };
}])
```

You can see a working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/scyrizales/zu2osuzb/